# How to I remove the grid to 'render only' in v 3.0 whilst still working on my object?

Tags: versions

The option use to be in a side bar under display. I cannot find where it is in V 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to viewport overlays and uncheck floor, the grid will disappear.

concerning render only:  According to other questions the grid itself will not ever be rendered.

[image]